# Projeto Vaadin erro no "pom.xml"

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

Criei um projeto Maven e fui colocando as dependências, fiquei com o erro no pom relacionado a dependência do *servlet* .

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Estou usando Java 7, Tomcat 7 e o Vaadin 7.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ainda não existe a versão 3.0.1, olhando no [repositório central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api), acredito que você quer a versão `3.0-alpha-1`.

Use a dependência desse jeito:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Math boa tarde! Você esta correto, alterei e o pom passou

Comment: @Robson às ordens. Se essa essa for a resposta correta pode marcá-la como aceita, para indicar que seu problema está resolvido. Se quiser entender melhor veja esse link: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117)

Comment: Math prezado Eu criei um novo projeto desta vez usando o plugin do vaadin no eclipse, ao terminar eu converti o projeto para Maven, ao final observei que ele configurou a dependência com a versão 3.0.1 do javax.servlet-api

Comment: @Robson não entendi muito bem onde quer chegar. Toda vez que cria um projeto novo ele cria automaticamente a dependência do 3.0.1 e dá o mesmo erro? Ou você está relatando que conseguiu usar uma dependência versão 3.0.1 com sucesso? Por favor, clarifique sua dúvida para que seja possível ajudá-lo.

Comment: Isto mesmo fiz um novo projeto e converti para Maven e não apresentou o erro no pom.xml como anteriormente, agora voltei ao meu projeto original e voltei a dependência o que eu mudei foi que não coloquei provided e passou sem problema.

Comment: @Robson É possível que quando você usou o plugin do Vaadin ele registrou localmente a dependência 3.0.1, pois ela com certeza não foi obtida através do repositório central. Eu acabei de criar um projeto (sem o plugin Vaadin, pois não tenho ele) e tentei adicionar a dependência sem o `provided` e não funcionou, logo, é possível que o seu erro tenha sido que na verdade na primeira vez ele não conseguiu registrar a dependência corretamente. À nivel de informação, poderia verificar se no conteúdo da pasta `C:\Users\Seu Usuário\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\3.0.1` tem algum .jar?